Show Vaadin Notification after page reload
In Vaadin I want to show a Notification after a page reload:
UI.getCurrent().getPage().reload();
new Notification("Success", 5000).open();

But with this attempt no notification is shown.
What is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Does smth. like UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("window.location.reload();").then(val -> {new Notification("Success", 5000).open();});  work?

Although it looks very imperative to show a notificiation, this still is part
of the state of UI; so when you reload, you are basically (re-)creating a fresh
state, where the notification is not part of.
You have to signal to the "new" UI, that you want something to be done.
One way to do this is by storing a marker inside the session (where all UIs are
part of).  Then use a observer on a component (or a listener for your whole
application) for when the navigation is done, to resolve the notification.
E.g.
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout)
@SuppressWarnings('unused')
class MainView extends Composite<Div> implements AfterNavigationObserver {

    public static final String RELOADED_KEY = 'reloaded'

    MainView() {
        content.add(
                new Button("Reload and notify", {
                    getUI().get().tap {
                        getSession().setAttribute(RELOADED_KEY, true)
                        getPage().reload()
                    }
                })
        )
    }

    @Override
    void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent afterNavigationEvent) {
        def session = getUI().get().getSession()
        if (session.getAttribute(RELOADED_KEY)) {
            session.setAttribute(RELOADED_KEY, false)
            Notification.show('Reloaded...')
        }
    }
}



If you want to observe a referesh event to take some action when that happens, then you need to preserve the UI on refresh. The UI is re-created otherwise as explained in @cfrick's answer above.
The way to do this is to annotate the view with @PreserveOnRefresh. Then implement the BeforeEnterObserver interface.
This gives you the beforeEnter method that you can override to show the notification on refresh.
@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (event.isRefreshEvent()) {
        Notification.show("Hello there");
    }
}

